# Create directory in ftp using php

Tags: php, ftp

well that's easy question, But confused about creating directory in already existing directories.

```
    $dirname = uniqid();
mkdir("/abc/xyz/", 0700); //mkdir("/abc/xyz/".$dirname, 0777);

// try to create directory $dir
if (ftp_mkdir($ftp_conn, $dirname)) 
{
  echo "Successfully created $dirname,<br>\r\n";
}
 else
 {
 echo "Error while creating $dirname\n";
  }

 // close connection
    ftp_close($ftp_conn);
```

i tried a lot,In ftp, i should create a folder in already existing xyz, xyz is already in abc. where abc is in home directory. whatever method i try, folder is getting created in home directory.i am trying to create directory with unique name and it's working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should include the complete path, otherwise the directory will always be created in the root ftp directory.

```
$path = "/abc/xyz/";
mkdir($path, 0700);
$dirname = $path . uniqid();
```

So if `uniqid()` was `1234` it should be created as `/abc/xyz/1234`

Comment: one question, why are you mentioning $path in $dirname..?

Comment: Since `$path` is `/abc/xyz/` it needs to be added in front of `uniqid`, making `dirname` `/abc/xyz/1234`. Without adding it,   `uniqid` (`1234`) won't know that it should be created in `/abc/xyz/` and instead default to the root in `abc`.